# How to get the order of complexity of a while/for loop with different ways of updating an index?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o, analytics

I am checking simple order of complexity problems and I found this one:

```
int example(int max) {
    int i  =  0;
    double x  =  0.0;

    while ( i <= max ) {
        x  =  doStuff(x , i); //doStuff is O(i)
        i  = i + 10 ;
    }
}
```

We know that `doStuff(int x, int i)` is of `O(i)`, and that the order of example should be based on `max`.

Now, i have seen and understood cases of loops running in `O(i)`,`O(log i)`, etc...but how would I get the order of the while loop (and thus the order of `example`)  when the index being checked and also passed to the function does grow in sums different than other usual `i++` or `2*i`?

Answer (score 1):

The case `i = i + 10` is not much different from `i++`:

The order of complexity of the whole algorithm is (where `/` is integer division, and *m* is `max`):

*O(0) + O(10) + O(20) + ... + O((m/10)*10)*

As *O(x) + O(y) = O(x + y)*, we can write this as:

*O(10(1+2+3+ ... +m/10))*

And we can apply the usual formula for the [triangle number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number):

*O(10(m/10)(m/10 - 1)/2)*

We only need the term with the highest order, and can ignore its coefficient:

*= O(m²)*